# I'm getting [object object] alert when I call json data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm getting [object object] alert when I call json data from online server not the localhost. It works perfectly on localhost. here's the aspx code

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnGetEmployee').click(function () {
            var empId = $('#txtId').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetEmployeeById',
                method: 'post',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: '{employeeId:' + empId + '}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#txtName').val(data.d.Name);
                    $('#txtGender').val(data.d.Gender);
                    $('#txtSalary').val(data.d.Salary);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

and here's the code behind

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Demo
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static Employee GetEmployeeById(int employeeId)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                    ["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetEmployeeById", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Id",
                Value = employeeId
            });
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                employee.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                employee.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                employee.Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                employee.Salary = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Salary"]);
            }
        }

        return employee;
    }
}
```

}

There's definitely some line haven't considered for online servers I wish someone with experience will answer me. 
Many thanks

Comment: If you use `console.log` instead of `alert` you will be able to see the error in the console.

Comment: @Turnip I'm getting this error 
statusText
:
"Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` to get proper json content.

Comment: this is the exact error comment i'm getting from Microsoft Edge HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR): POST - http://www.website.somee.com/EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployeeById